# System V - Respawn service but don't launch at boot

Tags: linux, services, sysvinit, system-v, busybox-init

I'm trying to have a System V service relaunched on exit.

***EDIT:*** Should have precised that I'm using busybox init system instead of classic systemV

I found that It could be done using `/etc/inittab` with the keyword `respawn` as action ([man inittab](https://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/man/inittab-man-page.php)).

> respawn
>   The process will be restarted whenever it terminates (e.g. getty).

This seems to be the right action to set, however with `respawn` the service will be launched at boot.

I would like to have this service restarted but only after it has been launched from command line.

**Is this possible to configure the service to respawn but not to be launched at boot ?**

Comment: Not that I can think of. `init` typically knows when to restart it because it started it to begin with and gets a signal when it terminates.  I don't know of a way to have it monitor some "other" process.

Comment: The respawn in inittab will always run it on boot. I don't think that solution is going to yield the results you want. I'd take a look at possibly doing something with [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) or [GOD](http://godrb.com/).